# recurring billing in php application using braintree payment gateway?

Tags: payment, braintree, recurring

If anyone can implemented the braintree payment gateway in php so help me to recurring billing in php application using braintree payment gateway

My Code is follows:

```
<?php function braintree_text_field($label, $name, $result) {

echo('<div>' . $label . '</div>');

$fieldValue = isset($result) ? $result->valueForHtmlField($name) : '';

echo('<div><input type="text" name="' . $name .'" value="' . $fieldValue . '" /></div>');

$errors = isset($result) ? $result->errors->onHtmlField($name) : array();

foreach($errors as $error) {

    echo('<div style="color: red;">' . $error->message . '</div>');

}

echo("\n");

}c

?>
```

```
<head>

    <title>Braintree Payment - Debt Relief</title>

</head>

<body>

    <?php

    if (isset($_GET["id"])) {

        $result = Braintree_TransparentRedirect::confirm($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

    }

    if (isset($result) && $result->success) { ?>

        <h1>Braintree Payment -Debt Relief</h1>

        <?php $transaction = $result->transaction; ?>

        <table>

            <tr><td>transaction id</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($transaction->id); ?></td></tr>

            <tr><td>transaction status</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($transaction->status); ?></td></tr>

            <tr><td>transaction amount</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($transaction->amount); ?></td></tr>

            <tr><td>customer first name</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($transaction->customerDetails->firstName); ?></td></tr>

            <tr><td>customer last name</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($transaction->customerDetails->lastName); ?></td></tr>

            <tr><td>customer email</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($transaction->customerDetails->email); ?></td></tr>

            <tr><td>credit card number</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($transaction->creditCardDetails->maskedNumber); ?></td></tr>

            <tr><td>expiration date</td><td><?php echo htmlentities($transaction->creditCardDetails->expirationDate); ?></td></tr>

        </table>

    <?php

    } else {

        if (!isset($result)) { $result = null; } ?>

        <h1>Braintree Payment -Debt Relief</h1>

        <?php if (isset($result)) { ?>

            <div style="color: red;"><?php echo $result->errors->deepSize(); ?> error(s)</div>

        <?php } ?>

        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo Braintree_TransparentRedirect::url() ?>" autocomplete="off">

            <fieldset>

                <legend>Customer</legend>

                <?php braintree_text_field('First Name', 'transaction[customer][first_name]', $result); ?>

                <?php braintree_text_field('Last Name', 'transaction[customer][last_name]', $result); ?>

                <?php braintree_text_field('Email', 'transaction[customer][email]', $result); ?>

            </fieldset>



            <fieldset>

                <legend>Payment Information</legend>



                <?php braintree_text_field('Credit Card Number', 'transaction[credit_card][number]', $result); ?>

                <?php braintree_text_field('Expiration Date (MM/YY)', 'transaction[credit_card][expiration_date]', $result); ?>

                <?php braintree_text_field('CVV', 'transaction[credit_card][cvv]', $result); ?>

            </fieldset>



            <?php

                define('TRANSACTION_PATH',BASE_URL.'admin/single_transactions');
             $tr_data = Braintree_TransparentRedirect::transactionData(

                array('redirectUrl' => TRANSACTION_PATH,

               /* array('redirectUrl' => BASE_PATH.'admin/single_transactions'. parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH),*/

                'transaction' => array('amount' => '10.00', 'type' => 'sale'))) ?>

            <input type="hidden" name="tr_data" value="<?php echo $tr_data ?>" />



            <br />

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

        </form>

    <?php } ?>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

Transparent Redirect does not support recurring billing, as you cannot create subscriptions with it. Please follow our [Recurring Billing guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/guides/recurring-billing/overview) for more information on how to use it.